# Trying to understand dictionary objects

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'd like to define my model in a variable and then use it in the data object (object A), but when I do this, it re-uses the same model instead of creating a new one. Seems I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here. Can anyone please explain why it's adding to the same object in object A?

```js
var dataObjectA = {};
var dataObjectB = {};

var model = { value: 0 }
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 dataObjectA[i] = model;
 dataObjectA[i].value++;
}


for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 dataObjectB[i] = { value: 0 }  
 dataObjectB[i].value++;
} 

console.log(dataObjectA); // all values: 10 --> how to make this all 1??
console.log(dataObjectB);// all values: 1
```

Comment: There's only one `model` object, and you're merely assigning a reference to it to `dataObjectA`. The right way to do it is the second way, as you already discovered.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 2):

```
   dataObjectA[i] = model;
```

`model` is a *reference* to the underlying object, so you put a reference into the dictionary. Therefore whenever you access one of these, you get the same reference, and therefore the same object. Just built up a new object in every loop iteration:

```
 dataObjectA[i] = { value: 0};
```

Or if you want to take the advantage of prototypal inheritance:

```
 dataObjectA[i] = Object.create(model);
```

Now all objects are different but they *inherit* from model.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the object reference in Js when you assing an object to a variable you are not creating a new object, you are just [referencing to the exiting object](https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

You can solve it by creating a new object from your model.

```js
var dataObjectA = {};
var dataObjectB = {};

var model = { value: 0 }
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 dataObjectA[i] =  Object.assign({}, model);
 dataObjectA[i].value++;
}


for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 dataObjectB[i] = { value: 0 }  
 dataObjectB[i].value++;
} 

console.log(dataObjectA); // all values: 10 --> how to make this all 1??
console.log(dataObjectB);// all values: 1
```